Nginx serving Django's media files only on port 80
I have searched here and other resources for the same issue. They all did not help. Please before closing this based on the fact that it is a duplicate, ask for more details and I will try to provide.
First of all, I am on Windows. I have created my django app, and configured my Nginx. I then ran the django app via:
uvicorn monitoring.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9001 --reload

I have created inbound rules on the server for port 9001, and the app runs smoothly. All the static files are being served via whitenoise library. All the Media files which users upload to the app are not being served. This includes images for some products as well as some other files, PDFs, etc.
I can access the files directly in the following way in the browser (notice the missing port number which will translate to port 80). This means that Nginx is performing its duty normally.
http://10.0.60.26/media/xxxx/xxxxxx.png

But not in the following way:
http://10.0.60.26:9001/media/xxxx/xxxxx.png

This gives a 404 error. Which is actually a correct behaviour since we are utalizing Nginx to serve these files not django.
I have no clue why this is happening that instead of directly fetching the media files via Nginx, the app is trying to fetch them from uvicorn.
Is there a way to make django to get these files directly from Nginx? I have already the following codes for instance:
<img src="{{ machine.image.url }}" alt="{{ machine.name }}">

which is equal to:
xxxx/xxxxx.png

Any advice or help would be appreciated.
settings.py:
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
#Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    ...
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
]
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myApp.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myApp.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'myApp.asgi.application'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
# Whitenoise settings
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
import os
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

nginx.conf (I have modified the config file which is in the Nginx folder)

#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        
        # Handle media files
        location /media/ {
            root C:/xxx/xxxx/myApp/media/;
        }

        # Handle static files
        location /static/ {
            alias C:/xxx/xxxx/myApp/staticfiles;
        }

        # Proxy all other requests to Uvicorn
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;  # Uvicorn is running on port 9001
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

I am not using Docker or anything and trying to run the app in production directly on the windows server.
Please do not suggest removing a slash from the url in Nginx or stuff like this. Believe me, a desperate developer like me has already done these things ;)
I have tried many other questions with the same issue, but mostly people with the issue were on linux/unix systems and were using 'gunicorn' or had issues with their docker files which does not apply to me.
